# Tensorflow uses CPU instead of GPU. How to fix?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to run the project using Anaconda, TensorFlow 2.3, Keras 2.4.3 (CNN example). OS Windows 10.

I installed Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition, CUDA 10.1 and cudnn 8.0.5 for CUDA 10.1.

Using Anaconda I created an environment with TensorFlow (tensorflow-gpu didn't help), Keras, matplotlib, scikit-learn. I tried to run it on CPU but it takes a lot of time (20 minutes for just 1 epoch when there are 35).

I need to run it using GPU, but TensorFlow doesn't see my GPU device (GeForce GTX 1060). Can someone help me find the problem? I tried to solve the problem using this guide [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu?hl=en)  but it didn't help me.
[image: GPU not found]

Comment: I believe you need to use cudnn 7.6.5 and  cudetoolkit 10.1.243 installed. Did you use pip to install tensorflow?

Comment: Please find my resolution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65478678/10157759).

Answer (score 1):

This works 100%, no need to install anything manually (cuda for example)

```
 conda create --name tf_gpu tensorflow-gpu
```

Comment: I used this command via Anaconda Powershell Prompt. It still uses CPU. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I tried to install all the components into new anaconda environment. But instead of "conda install tensorflow-gpu" I decided to write "pip install tensorflow-gpu" and now it works via GPU...

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, the Cudnn version you were trying to use was incompatible.
[Listing Versions and compatible CUDA+Cudnn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JTbb.png)

You can go [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows) and then scroll down to the bottom to see what versions of CUDA and Cudnn were used to build TensorFlow.